# Disable check box after i purchased something using php

Tags: php

I am using php I need to disable the checkbox after I purchased something. I already done this before its working perfectly. But I slightly changed the code for another purchase. i.e I added new product and purchased it, but its reflecting I need to disable it. I don't know where I missed. Can anyone help me?

Here my code

```
$mem_id = $_SESSION['mrid'];
             $product = array();

             $Purchased_product = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE reg_id = '".$mem_id."' and status=1");
             $product_details = array();
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Purchased_product)) {                               
                  $product_details[] = $row['prod'];    
              }
             $result3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM product_table");
             while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
                  $single_pur_details = array();
                  $single_pur_details['product_pur'] =  $row3['product'];
                  $single_pur_details['product_amt'] =  $row3['product_price'];

                  $product[] = $single_pur_details;

              }

                unset($product_details[4]);//Here I deleted my new product in array

          foreach($product as $key=>$row) {
              $productName = str_replace(" ","_",$row["product_pur"]);
              if(in_array($row["product_pur"],$product_details))
              {
                 $disabled = 'disabled';

              }
              else {
                  $disabled = '';
              }

              echo '<div><input type="checkbox"  '.$disabled.' class="product_input" name="product_name_'.$key.'" value='.$productName.'/'.$row["product_amt"].' /> '.$row["product_pur"].' </div>';

          }
```

Comment: it should be `if(in_array($productName,$product_details))` instead of `if(in_array($row["product_pur"],$product_details))` , no ?

Comment: No. Hamza abdaoui its just the product name to set the value for input